# How to convert integer in to base -2 using JAVA

Tags: java, algorithm, binary

If given int array A is [1,0,0,1,1] =9 A[i]*(-2)^i (^ power).
 How to write a java program get the int array sequence for give integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] arr = {1,0,0,1,1};
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i]=9*arr[i]*(int)Math.pow(-2,i);
        }
    } System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Comment: I wonted to convert to integer to binary not the binary to integer